# Auth0 java-jwt library fails to verify a valid token

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, auth0

I'm using the Auth0 `java-jwt` library to generate JWT tokens, however, once generated I'm not able to verify the tokens.

This is the code I use to generate the token:

```
final JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(secret);
final HashMap<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
claims.put("user", user);
claims.put("email", user.getEmail());
final String jwt = signer.sign(claims);
return jwt;
```

This is my secret and the token (it verifies correctly in https://jwt.io/):

> **secret**:
>   sfnd984f94j3fjn
>
> **token**: eyJ0eXBlIjoiSldUIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoyLCJlbWFpbCI6InNhbnRob3NoQHh5ei5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCRHSlNNRGtRRUEvRVNsRENJcVlud0R1Ly45YWRqRWRQalVvSWVKUmlsSmpSeHh6N2s2Q01xQyIsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJzYW50aG9zaCIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6Imt1bWFyIiwic3RhdHVzIjoxLCJ0aXRsZSI6IkFzc29jIiwicm9sZXMiOlt7ImlkIjoxLCJyb2xlIjoiVVNFUiJ9XX0sImVtYWlsIjoic2FudGhvc2hAeHl6LmNvbSJ9.0SHNCgUWOijpYv7xcNoPiCwg_OFZQnsdi5l7YhCsSjU

When I use the same JWT token to verify it using the Auth0 method it fails (always ends up with a signature exception):

```
try {           
    final JWTVerifier verifier = new JWTVerifier(secret);
    final Map<String, Object> claims= verifier.verify(jwt);
    final String email = (String)claims.get("email");
    user =  userService.loadUserByEmail(email);
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
    // Invalid Token
} catch (SignatureException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) { 
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
```

I debugged the library and I think this is where the issue is (in `JWTVerifier` class):

```
void verifySignature(String[] pieces, String algorithm) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {

    Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(decoder.decodeBase64(secret), algorithm));
    byte[] sig = hmac.doFinal(
        new StringBuilder(pieces[0]).append(".").append(pieces[1]).toString().getBytes());

    if (!Arrays.equals(sig, decoder.decodeBase64(pieces[2]))) {
        throw new SignatureException("signature verification failed");
    }
}
```

This looks wrong to me because the `pieces[1]` and `pieces[0]` are decoded with the `hmac.doFinal` where as the `pieces[2]` is just plain base64 decoded.

Is my assumption right. Is this a bug in the library or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The version of `JWTVerifier` being used assumes that the secret you pass is Base64url encoded so it automatically decodes it before using it** as the key to validate the signature.

Given `sfnd984f94j3fjn` is the actual secret and your version of `JWTVerifier` automatically Base64url decodes whatever you pass it, **you need to encode `sfnd984f94j3fjn` in Base64url and pass the encoded version to `JWTVerifier`**.

Something similar to this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// ...

Base64 encoder = new Base64(true);

encoder.encodeBase64("sfnd984f94j3fjn".getBytes());
```

---

You can see the automatic decoding of the secret happening on the following line of the version of `JWTVerifier` class you're using:

```
hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(decoder.decodeBase64(secret), algorithm));
```

---

An update on this, the latest version of the library does not seem to assume a Base64url encoding.

Comment: They should update their documentation. Its not apparent. thanks.

Comment: According to [this commit](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/commit/1e6f68764b26f62d39b04da6eca878c0989c6e5a), secrets are no longer assumed to be Base64 so there may be a mismatch between the version you're using and the online docs.